# making 2 divs the same height and width using bootstrap/css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make these 2 divs for a table the same height and width with these codes

```
<div class="container">
    {{#if orders}}
    <div class="filter">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills tab ">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link tablinks active" href="#">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cars</a>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicing</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="table">
        <table class="table tab text-nowrap">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Order ID</th>
                    <th>Customer ID</th>
                    <th>Product ID</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Order Date</th>
                    <th>Delivery Status</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active {
  background-color: #8B0000;
  color: white;
}


.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.tab a {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #000000;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #8B0000;
  color: white;
}
```

After I added the text-nowrap in the table class, my table looked like this now, so how can I fix the div filter to be the same height and width as my table header?
[how it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlL5g.png)

Thank you so much?

Comment: Can you add your current CSS?

Comment: @DianaLe Done! I think the css I have mainly just changes the colours since I used bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with Bootstrap 4.6.1 but this issue also occurs in version 5. The problem is at smaller browser widths, the table width is wider than the Bootstrap container. Since HTML tables will never wrap columns or shrink smaller than their columns allow by default, this is what's causing the widths not to match. I've adjusted by adding a wrapper around the table that will fit within the container and will allow for scrolling the table horizontally instead, but this may not be what you're looking for in regards to UI. But there will have to be some adjustment made to either scroll, allow the table column names to wrap, or changing them to a dropdown, etc.

Even if you used flexbox instead of a table, at some point the headings will be too small to fit horizontally in one line.

As far as the height, depending on which one you want to change, you will either need to adjust the padding on `.table td, .table th` or on `.tab a`

```css
.nav-pills .nav-link.active {
  background-color: #8B0000;
  color: white;
}

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.tab a {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #000000;
}

thead th {
  background-color: #8B0000;
  color: white;
}

.table-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="filter">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills tab ">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link tablinks active" href="#">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cars</a>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table">
      <table class="table tab text-nowrap">
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th>Order ID</th>
            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Unit Price</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Delivery Status</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```